# Running phar files from a browser

Tags: php, iis-8, phar

Is it possible to run .phar files from a browser?  A couple of sites seem to suggest that it is, but I can't find any details on how to set it up.

I can run phar files directly from the CLI, but not from a browser.  I'm using IIS.  What do I need to do to make it work?

I'm on PHP 7.2 and IIS 8.5.

I know I can "include" them in regular php scripts, but I want to know how to run them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell IIS that `.phar` files should be handled with the PHP CGI process.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php

In step 14 "Add Module Mapping", you need to set the "Request Path" to `*.phar`.